# in blender when i open up, weird diagonal line

Tags: 3d-view

there is a line starting at the top left going to the bottom right. everything in the bottom left portion is normal, but the top right portion is a inverted version of the other, you cannot see anything other then the inverted image. this is including the 3d plane where the cube is on startup. ive tried repairing, reseting, even reinstalling blender, the weird part tho is that when i resize the viewbox, its normal while its moving then goes back to what it was before. [image: weird behavior]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try to update your gpu drivers, and see if that helps, other than that, I could be a bug